# Error importing cloud-spanner on apache beam 2.9

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am trying to update a few python apache beam scripts to the recent 2.9 version of apache beam. I am running into the following error when running a script that imports `from google.cloud.spanner import Client` on the google cloud dataflow runner (direct runner works fine):
https://gist.github.com/pascaldelange/f43cc1f6dc290291804b64b0db1cadfe

I have a proper setup.py that was working fine pre-2.9
with in particular

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    "Flask==0.12.2",
    "apache-beam[gcp]==2.9",
    "gunicorn==19.7.1",
    "gevent==1.2.1",
    "google-api-core==1.7.0",
    "google-apitools==0.5.24",
    "google-auth==1.6.2",
    "google-cloud-bigquery==1.6.1",
    "google-cloud-core==0.29.0",
    "google-cloud-pubsub==0.35.4",
    "google-cloud-spanner==1.7.1",
    "google-cloud-storage==1.13.1",
    "google-resumable-media==0.3.1",
    "googleapis-common-protos==1.5.5",
    "googledatastore==7.0.2",
    "grpc-google-iam-v1==0.11.4",
    "proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1==0.90.4",
    "six==1.11",
]
```

Perhaps related: on a different job (streaming), I  have error logs

```
No unique name set for transform generatedPtransform-45
```

and

```
Missing required coder_id on grpc_port for -3; using deprecated fallback.
```

Though they do not appear to actually block execution

What could cause this error, specifically only using the google cloud dataflow runner ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
Missing required coder_id on grpc_port for -3; using deprecated fallback.
```

was introduced in beam 2.9 and still exists in 2.10.

While [the commit that added this error](https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/8d7ad50bc32185dce7f70eaaf71ee7e96ccfd24f) logs with 'error' severity, it doesn't seem to actually break anything.

Here is the beam jira issue for more details:

https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5415